# How can I open Field Service Lightning from my own app?

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, ios, deep-linking, mobile-url-scheme

I have one iOS app and I want to add a link to open Field Service Lightning app from there. Is there any URL Scheme like Saleforce1 has?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce released Deep Linking Schema for the Field Service Lightning Mobile App
in summer'19 release
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.field_service_dev.meta/field_service_dev/fsl_dev_mobile_deep_linking_schema.htm